# Incorrect operation of filters NativeQuery.builder() in "operations.multiSearch(queryList, classes, indexCoordinatesList)"

Tags: html, elasticsearch, spring-data

I applied "multiSearch" in ElasticSearch in this way:
`List<Search Hits<?>> search Hits = operations.multiSearch(queryList, classes, index CoordinatesList);`

"queryList" contains "filmQuery" which normally works in this variant:
`SearchHits<Film> filmSearchHits = operations.search(filmQuery, Film.class , FILM_INDEX_COORDINATES);`

But by executing the "filmQuery" in "multiSearch" as part of the "queryList", the filters does not work, the query is executed only in this part:

```
.withQuery(q -> q. match(ma -> ma
            .field("title")
            .value(titleInLowercase)));
```

The filmQuery itself is below:

```
     Query filmQuery = NativeQuery.builder()
    .withQuery(q -> q. match(ma -> ma
            .field("title")
            .value(titleInLowercase)));
    .withFilter(f -> f
        .bool(b -> {...}
    .build();
```

Tell me, please, what could be the problem.